# Copying the icon of target file to its shortcut in Python

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm a beginner at programming and recently started experimenting with creating shortcuts using python.
I know how to create a shortcut using `win32com` client but was wondering how to copy the same icon of the target file to its shortcut that is being created.

To illustrate, here is the code:

```py
import win32com.client
path = r"D:\\meh.lnk"
target = r"D:\\Python\words.txt"
icon = r"" # i dont have any icon to attach here yet.
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.IconLocation = icon
```

So I was wondering how I can set the path of the original target file's icon to the the `icon`
variable, to attach it to its shortcut, or some other way to achieve the same goal.

I haven't really tried anything yet because i dont know where to start, i did try to put the same path of the target file to the `icon` variable, but that did not work.

EDIT: Ok so, the solution to this is not to set the `IconLocation` manually, the icon is set automatically from the target file unless it is set manually.

Comment: Works for me. In fact trying to set the *IconLocation* property throws an exception. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CristiFati This is'nt the exact code that I was using, setting the IconLocation attribute throws an exception because it doesn't take empty strings, I left the string empty just to represent the structure of my code. I added a comment denoting the fact that I don't have an icon to actually set the attribute to.

Comment: I see now. Nevertheless, in my case it's working OK without setting it.

Comment: Don't set the icon, but remember to include `shortcut.Save()` otherwise the shortcut won't get created. In my tests, the icon of the link automatically picks up the icon of the target file. Indeed it seems that the `IconLocation` is set to `,0`. There are more complicated ways to get the icon location for `.txt` files in general, but I don't think you need that here. NB use `shell.CreateShortcut(path)` instead: note case of "Shortcut" to prevent unexpected issues down the line.

Comment: @DS_London omg finally something that worked. Yes not setting the `IconLocation` manually works perfectly, it sets the icon itself. Thank you for this, Such a small detail, yet I could not find it anywhere.